# Finding the area on a graph defined by parametric equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, circles

> Find the area enclosed by the graph of the parametric equations:
>   \begin{align*}
> x & = 6 \cos(t) \sin(t), \\
> y & = 6 \cos^2(t).
> \end{align*}

Should I multiply the top equation by $-\cos(t)$?  Then I could do like, $y-x = 30 \cos ^2(t) \sin^2(t)$?

Comment: $x = 3 \sin 2t, y = 3\cos 2t - 3$  What sort of shape is that?  What is the area?

Comment: Change the negative sign in the right hand side of y= 3 cos2t-3 to a positive sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $x^2+(y-3)^2=9$, which gives the answer: $9\pi$.