# parametric equations meet at $2$ points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

The graph of the parametric equations
\begin{align*}
x&=\cos t,\\ 
y&=\sin t
\end{align*}
meets the graph of the parametric equations
\begin{align*}
x &= 2+ 4\cos s,\\
y &= 3+4\sin s
\end{align*}
at two points. Find the slope of the line between these two points.

I graphed it out on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/), but it wouldn't give me the points.
How should I solve?

Comment: Are you aware that you are looking for the intersections (if they exist) of two circles?

Comment: The first curve is $x^2+y^2=1$ and the second $(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2=16$. Subtracting both equations we get another equation that also passes through the intersection. That other equation happens to be a line. The new equation is $4x-4+6y-9=-16$. Compute its slope $-4/6$.

Comment: You asked a very similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362162/finding-the-area-on-a-graph-defined-by-parametric-equations  Perhaps you'd like to add details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parametrization of 
\begin{align*}
x&=\cos t  \hspace{4mm}\mbox{ and }  \hspace{4mm}
y=\sin t 
\end{align*}
is the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ of radius $1$ and the parametrization of 
\begin{align*}
x &= 2+ 4\cos s \hspace{4mm}\mbox{ and } \hspace{4mm} 
y = 3+4\sin s 
\end{align*}
is the circle $(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2=16$ of radius $4$. 
Expand $(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2=16$ to get  $x^2 - 4 x +13 + y^2 - 6 y =16$. 
Then 
$$
x^2+y^2-(x^2 - 4 x +13 + y^2 - 6 y )= \color{green}{-13 + 4 x + 6 y}=1-16\color{green}{=-15}. 
$$
Since 
$3y=-2x-1$, we have 
$$
y=-\frac{2}{3}x-\frac{1}{3}. 
$$
Thus the slope between the two points at the intersection of the two circles is 
$$
-\frac{2}{3}. 
$$